# Xcode no longer able to find cocoapods after update to 1.01 -- even after reverting back to 0.39

Tags: xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

Here's the sequence of events:

(1) My project was working just fine with Cocoapods for months.

(2) I added a pod, `pod 'PKRevealController'` and ran `pod install`.

(3) Xcode could not find the new pod header and could not `#import PKRevealController`

(4) I thought since Cocoapods had been prompting me to update, now would be a good time, so I updated from 0.39 to 1.01

(5) After the update, Xcode could find NONE of the Pod headers--project is unbuildable.

(6) I reverted back to 0.39 and did `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`. Still nothing works.

My HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS look fine and are exactly as they were when the project worked. My Podfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'
link_with 'sunscope', 'sunscopeTests'
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
    # More pods...
end

target 'sunscope' do
    shared_pods
    # More pods...
end

target 'sunscopeTests' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm about to start crying.

Comment: Are you getting any errors after pod install ?

Comment: Delete the Podfile.lock, .workspace and Pods folder. Copy the contents of the Podfile and then delete it. Then run 'pod init'. Move the contents of the old Podfile to the new Podfile. Now run 'pod install' again. Hope it helps.

Comment: @7vikram7 I tried that :(. I also removed the build phases and just completely remove all traces of cocoapods from my project before pod init and pod install.

Comment: @Chepe77 No I'm getting no errors or warnings on pod install

Comment: I remember facing a similar issue. I resolved it by updating my pods to latest version. So instead of updating to 1.0.1, why don't you try it with version 1.0.0. I am currently using it, and it works fine.

Comment: I tried everything including reinstalling Cocoapods, clearing the cocoapods cache, of course removing all traces from my project, and running pod install again. I'd been meaning to look into Carthage, and so switched over to Carthage today and got everything working. I still have no clue what I did to make Cocoapods angry at me.